# Python: Find a sublist in a list, and print the next element in the list

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have two lists like this

```
#Main List
    0       1        2      3        4      5       6        7       8       9       10       11
['blue', 'crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold', 'blue', 'blue', 'crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold', 'blue']
```

```
    #Sublist

['crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold']
```

I wish to find the sublist in the main list (if it exists). If found, I wish to print the next occurring element in the list.

For instance, for the two lists above, I wish to have this as an output:

```
'blue'
'blue'
```

the first 'blue' comes from the 5th element of the list, which is located just after the first occurrence of the sublist (L[0:4]). The second 'blue' comes from the 11th element of the main list, which is also located after the second occurrence of the substring in the List.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Cool. Do it, come back if you have a specific problem with your code you created to get to what you want. Then post an [mre] and describe your problem.

Comment: I dont know how to do it at all

Comment: `print(*((k+len(['crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold']),sl[-1]) for (k,sl) in ((k, ['blue', 'crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold', 'blue', 'blue', 'crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold', 'blue'][k:k+len(['crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold'])+1]) for k in range(len(['blue', 'crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold', 'blue', 'blue', 'crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold', 'blue'])-len(['crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold']))) if sl[:len(['crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold'])]==['crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold']), sep="\n")` there you go. optimize it by replacing repeats of things by variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the list, look for the sublist and print the next element if it's found:

```
List = ['blue', 'crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold', 'blue', 'blue', 'crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold', 'blue']
Sublist = ['crash', 'pink', 'pink', 'gold']

for i in range(len(List)-len(Sublist)): #Loop over the List
    if List[i:i+len(Sublist)] == Sublist:  #If we find the sublist in the List
            print(List[i+len(Sublist)])    #we print it
```

Comment: You're welcome, but please try to improve your question and be more precise on the issue you're having, so other people can understand it too. It took me a while to get what your problem was.